# can you take ram from a windows xp computer to windows 10 computer

Tags: memory

can you switch ram from your windows xp to your 10 my grandparents use to have a old windows xp computer they dont use anymore and i want to swap the ram from it to my windows 10 gaming pc i have 32 gigybites and i dont know how much is on the windows xp but i can i put the ram on my gaming pc because i want to download some games so putting a little ram will help me a ton with saving storage

Comment: No you cannot, ram from that XP pc will not fit. If you post the make and model of each PC this can be verified for sure.

Answer (score 4):

If the machines are of a similar vintage and have the same type of RAM then yes. If the computers use completely different RAM then no.

Given that the older computer is Windows XP it will likely have either DDR or DDR2 RAM.  Your newer computer (probably) uses DDR4.

These are not compatible and you cannot use DDR RAM in a DDR4 slot, it simply will not fit.

You would not want to either. RAM works at the speed of the slowest module and DDR would slow your machine down significantly. Chances are also that the module in the XP machine is less than 1GB in size would give you no worthwhile benefit.